# lwjgl back face renders regardless of winding

Tags: opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I am working on a 3d engine using lwjgl, and I am trying to render a simple cube, but only the away-facing faces are rendering, as if the faces were wound the wrong way, and neither winding the faces the other way or changing opengl's winding direction using `glFrontFace` fixes the problem.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

[Here's a screenshot of the cube](http://i.imgur.com/9cmT02R.png)

My projection matrix is:

```
(1/tan(fov*0.00872))/aspect  0                   0                0
0                            1/tan(fov*0.00872)  0                0 
0                            0                   -far/(far-near)  (far*near)/(far-near)
0                            0                   1                0
```

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Can you show your projection matrix?

Comment: Do you have culling turned on? If so, are you culling front faces?

Comment: @user1118321 I haven't enabled culling, so unless it is enabled by default it isn't turned on, but if that were the problem, then reversing the winding direction should fix it, but I get the same result regardless of which way I wind the faces

Comment: OK, so probably not the winding or culling. Is your depth test reversed, by any chance? For example, are you using `GL_GREATER` when it should be `GL_LESS`?

Comment: I've tried using `GL_GREATER`, `GL_GEQUAL`, `GL_LESS`, and `GL_LEQUAL`, and `GL_LESS` and `GL_LEQUAL` both give the same result. `GL_GREATER` and `GL_GEQUAL` however seem to cause nothing to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. Instead of the depth buffer being in the range 0 to 1, it was somehow (I have no idea how) in the range 0 to -1. Using `GL_LEQUAL` as the depth function caused the further faces to be rendered rather than the closer ones, and using `GL_GEQUAL` caused nothing to be rendered because the background with depth 0 was always greater than anything in the scene. I fixed the problem by using `GL_GEQUAL` and setting the default background depth to -1 using `GL11.glClearDepth();`